# Does $ M(x)=O(\sqrt{x}) $ if and only if the De Bruijn-Newman constant is negative?

Tags: nt.number-theory, analytic-number-theory, l-functions, riemann-hypothesis

The Riemann hypothesis is equivalent to the assertion that the De Bruijn-Newman constant  $ \Lambda $ , as defined in https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0001870809001133/pdf?md5=d2b0cbb38f79b80de06d8b9c99836fab&pid=1-s2.0-S0001870809001133-main.pdf&_valck=1, fulfills  $ \Lambda\leq 0 $. On the other hand, Newman conjectured that  $ \Lambda\geq 0 $, so that RH, if true, would be only barely so. So far it has been proven that  $ -1.1\times 10^{-12}\lt\Lambda\lt 1/2 $.

Another assertion equivalent to RH is  $ M(x)\ll_{\varepsilon}x^{1/2+\varepsilon} $ where  $ M $ is the Mertens function defined as the summatory function of the Möbius function, and it has been proven that the stronger statement  $ M(x)=O(\sqrt{x}) $ is incompatible with the great linear independence hypothesis, stating that, under RH, the imaginary parts of the standard L-functions are linearly independent over  $ \mathbb{Q} $, the latter being widely believed to be true.

That way, the possibility that  $M(x)=O(\sqrt{x}) $ may be too good to be true sounds similar to Newman's conjecture.
So my question is : is  $ M(x)=O(\sqrt{x}) $ actually equivalent to  $ \Lambda\lt 0 $?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The de Bruijn-Newman constant is nonnegative, as proved in this brand new [preprint](https://arxiv.org/abs/1801.05914) by Rodgers and Tao. It is also conjectured, but not proven yet, that $M(x)=O(\sqrt{x})$ is false, in which case it is actually equivalent to $\Lambda<0$. Time will tell.

Comment: Wonderful ! I would not have thought that Newman's conjecture would be proven in my lifetime. Maybe a proof of RH will follow...Thank you very much for your answer.

Comment: @SylvainJULIEN: You are welcome. Actually, I was (or rather: we are) lucky as Rogders and Tao just proved the conjecture. There is a lot of activity and amazing progress in analytic number theory these days, thanks to great mathematicians captivated by the subject.

Comment: @GHfromMO Hello GH, could you please elaborate on equivalence of $M(x)=O(\sqrt x)$ and $\Lambda<0$, or include a reference?

Comment: I did not say that these two statements are equivalent. I said that *if* $M(x)=\sqrt{x}$ is false (as expected) *then* it is equivalent to $\Lambda<0$ (which is false by the preprint quoted). My claim is trivial, because any two false statements are equivalent.